# Should I Track Revisions or Revision Diffs in a Database?

Tags: database, triggers, audit-trail

If I want to track revision history (ie. keep an audit trail) on a `foo` table, I might add a trigger to it, such that every `UPDATE` too `foo.some_text_column` also results in an `INSERT` into a `foo_history` table.

My question is, in that `foo_history` table, is it better to save the entire contents of `foo.some_text_column`, or to save just a "diff" of the changes?

In other words, if I update `'abc'` to `'def'`, is it better to keep the whole original text:

```
abc
```

or is it better to keep something more like ...

```
- abc
+ def
```

Obviously, the dif takes up more space for this short string, but when you have larger strings, with edits of just a few characters, the diff will be a lot smaller.

Also, I know databases are good at optimizing redundant data, so maybe storing the whole original text really isn't that bad?  I'm just honestly not sure which option make more sense, technically, and would welcome an informed opinion.

Comment: There certainly can be cases where duplicating `some_text_column` in the history table is prohibitively expensive, but it's impossible to know based on the details you have provided (at the very least the DBMS you're using; the size of the column and the rate/distribution of changes). E.g. on MSSQL fields >8000 bytes [will be stored outside of the main table and will not be compressed at all](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78323/alternative-way-to-compress-nvarcharmax)

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a general best practice for handling audit tracking on "documents" (ie. variable-sized amounts of text).  It sounds like there isn't.

Comment: Sure: you do need to consider the size of the "documents", the DBMS, and the rate of changes. Smaller text columns can be tracked in their entirety (I've seen & implemented this many times). Larger or frequently updated "documents" may need some extra care -- I wouldn't implement Google Docs-like revision history by storing the complete text of each revision as a VARCHAR(max) in an MSSQL database.